# When will it rain vs when does it going to rain?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> When will it rain?

> When does it going to rain?

Do the above sentences have the same meaning?

Comment: Your second sentence is incorrect; did you mean to ask "When **is** it going to rain?"

Answer (score 1):

The auxiliary verb in your second sentence should be "is", not "does". One says "It is going to rain", not "It does going to rain", so to make a question, one says "Is it going to rain?", not "Does it going to rain?".

Apart from that: yes, the two sentences

> When will it rain?

and

> When is it going to rain?

have the same meaning.

Answer (score 0):

> When will it rain?

expresses your certainty, even though there might be no indication of coming rain.

> When is it going to rain?

Note that it should be *is*, not *does*. It's a question based on present evidence (the sky clouded over, or you listened to a weather forecast and learnt that rain is expected).

I think the former is less common. I personally wouldn't use *will* with activities/events I have no control over.